# My .tex file does not pick up more than 9 entries from my .bib file

Tags: bibtex

Whilst creating my bibliography in TexStudio, my .tex file creates the first 9 entries correctly but does not show the 10th entry. However, TexStudio messages that the process exited normally.

All 10 entries are seen in the .bib file when opened in TexStudio, but the .bbl file only shows 9 entries when opened in TexStudio.

Do I need to specify the max. number of items that can be added to the .bbl file? If so, where?

Comment: did you try with `\nocite{*}`

Comment: Or make sure to cite all of the items.

Comment: Another possibility is that there is a syntax error in the entry that is not showing up. Can you edit your question and show the bib entry that is not appearing?

Comment: by default (unless you use `\nocite{*}` only entries that you cite in the document are added to the generated bibliography, the bib file should be thought of as a database of possible references, not the entries for the document.

Comment: Thanks David; the entry which I had added that did not show was not cited in the paper. The next entry I just added is cited and shows up correctly.

Comment: Check list: does the `.aux` file contain `\citation{...}` where `...` exactly matches your missing entry; did you rerun `bibtex` and LaTeX after modifying the `.tex` file; does the `.blg` file contain any warnings?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in comments